# Build regex for specific ID

Tags: regex

I got this data

```
L1349604 [AGL000901493]
```

And I only want to extract this L1349604.

Of course the number can be different. But it is a leading L everytime.

My regex is:

```
([A-Za-z0-9])
```

but it doesnt get me the result I want. Can someone please help?
Thanks.

Comment: What programming language are you using?  A simple Split() over a space will get you what you want, in many programming languages.

Comment: `(L[0-9]+)` ? assuming it's an L followed by numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex:

```
^L[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

or simply:

```
^L[0-9]+
```

if `L` is only followed with *digits*

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Regex | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `L` | Matches a single letter L |
| `[A-Za-z0-9]+` | Matches a sequence of one or more alphanumeric characters |